# What's the reason for wiring a relay this way?

Tags: relay, wiring, automotive, diagram, terminal

I came across the following automotive wiring diagram:

[image: Automotive wiring diagram]

One thing I don't quite understand is the way they wired the relay. I've got two main questions.

1. It appears to me that they used the exact same wire from terminal 87 to provide power to terminal 86. I don't think that there is anything wrong with this approach, but I haven't seen it before. The exact same wire gauge is used although one would expect that the load (the radiator fan) draws more current than the relay coil, right? Why did they do it this way?
2. Why did they connect battery positive (30) to terminal 87 on the relay? Why didn't they use terminal 30 on the relay? It makes no sense to me, but I guess there must be a good reason.

Comment: I'm really not getting your point...if the coolant is hot, the relay switches the radiator fan on.  Seems logical enough to me.

Comment: I'm a beginner, so please bear with me. I'm sure this works like it's supposed to, but I'm not used to seeing a relay wired like this.

Comment: "DIN standard - we don't need no stinkin DIN std" :-). ie often enough people will wire something like this is a manner which makes sense functionally without regard to there being "proper" numbering. That's life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing strange there - it's just how they've drawn it that's strange.  Let me re-draw it as a proper schematic for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fODDzX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch turns on the relay activates and power flows to the motor (depicted as a lamp here - circuitlab doesn't have a motor).

Why did they wire the battery to pin 87 and not pin 30? Simply because then the motor would be on all the time and the relay would do nothing.

Why did they use the same gauge wire?  Simple economy of scale.  They're already using that gauge elsewhere, so why fork out on a different, smaller, gauge as well when they don't need to?

Comment: Well, they did use 20-gauge wire from the relay's coil (pin 85) to ground. So it is a good question why the wire from the switch to the relay's other coil pin (#86) is 14-gauge. Assuming I'm reading the OP's diagram correctly... which I might not.

Comment: But not in brown and red, only in brown. Having brown and red in 20 gauge is a whole new reel of cable.

Comment: Why would the motor be on all the time if terminal 30 was used?

Comment: If you connect the battery to the same pin as the motor the motor is getting power from the battery.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff It might also be to do with the connectors on the relay - the ones with 14 awg may not be able to take 20.

Comment: @Majenko Of course, but then the load would be connected to terminal 87. That's a convention, right?

Comment: @Willem-AartvanDorpen You didn't say anything at all about moving the load - just the battery.  If you move the load as well, *and* move the connection to the thermal switch, then there is no difference in the schematic - a relay's switch is electrically identical both ways round - it's just a bit of metal that is moved by a magnet.

Comment: Apologies, my bad! I guess the real question is why they don't conform to the DIN standard.

Comment: I would say the pin on the relay numbered 30 should actually be numbered 87b.  Probably someone in the draft shop getting mixed up is all - since the wire eventually makes its way to 30 once it's gone through the relay.

Comment: Although the schematic looks strange, and is harder to understand electrically, it's actually conveying _more_ information drawn like that - it's showing how it's physically wired, in the car, rather than a purely theoretical drawing like majenko's

Comment: One reason to use the AWG 10 wire all the way to terminal 86 is so that if there's a short in that part of the circuit you know the fuse F1 will blow before the shorted wire sets something on fire. At least that's how its done in residential wiring --- the size of the circuit breaker determines the guage of wire you need to use.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Exactly.  Shorts and partial shorts from wiring to the frame (ground) should be considered a plausible failure mode.  Wiring needs to be sized not according to the amount of current carrying it, but by the size of the fuse feeding it.  In the US, it's acceptable to protect appliance cords with fuses downstream of them, but vehicles are expected to be subjected to harsher conditions (e.g. collisions with other vehicles) that make shorts to the frame more likely, and thus require wires to be protected upstream.

Answer (score 4):

If you draw this as a schematic, it would look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWBwNO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Terminals 30 and 87 are electrically equivalent - the circuit will work the same, regardless of which way they are connected.

The connection from terminal 87 to 86 goes through the thermal switch, so the switch will control the fan.

Comment: "Terminals 30 and 87 are electrically equivalent - the circuit will work the same, regardless of which way they are connected." — And that's exactly why I don't understand that they used 87 instead of 30. Why wouldn't they conform to the DIN standard?

Comment: Terminals 30 and 87 are not equivalent.  They are the 2 ends of the relay contacts. They are only connected when the relay coil is energized.  The relay coil is only energized when the coolant switch closes.  If power were applied directly to pin 30, then the fan would always be on which is not what is wanted.

Comment: @barry: 87 and 30 are equivalent, in the sense that if all connections on terminal 87 are moved to 30, and vice versa, the circuit would still work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using bigger size wire for the relay coil, to reduce inventory, is okay.
2. The relay terminal numbers shown do not comply to standards.

Correct terminal numbers are 85  - Relay coil +ve, 86  - Relay coil -ve, 87  - Relay contact common, 87b - Normally open contact.

Reference - DIN 72552
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_72552.

Comment: All the relays I've got have a terminal 30. I guess none of them comply to the standards.